# CS50 mario-less problem: Pyramid is printing but still have "did you add too much trailing whitespace to the end of your pyramid"?

Tags: c, less, cs50

I'm really new at coding so as expected I run into problems.
I cannot understand why my "very simple" solution for Mario Less problem doesn't pass the run tests. I know that it doesn't follow the exact steps as mentioned, but the output of the pyramid is correct (as I think).
I have no problem with learning new stuff, so I'm not trying to cheat out my way thru CS50. I just want to know why this option is not correct. The pyramid is printed, but I have "not pass":

:( handles a height of 1 correctly
Cause
expected ""#"", not ""#""
did you add too much trailing whitespace to the end of your pyramid? comment on check50.

Also checks for different inputs are not passed.

Thanks.

my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;

    // user communication
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height of the pyramid in steps: ");
        if (height < 1 || height > 8)
        {
        printf("Height must be between 1 an 8 steps. Try again. \n");
        }
    }

    while (height < 1 || height > 8);

    //build pyramid

        if (height == 1)
        printf("#");
        if (height == 2)
        printf(" #\n##");
        if (height == 3)
        printf("  #\n ##\n###");
        if (height == 4)
        printf("   #\n  ##\n ###\n####");
        if (height == 5)
        printf("    #\n   ##\n  ###\n ####\n#####");
        if (height == 6)
        printf("     #\n    ##\n   ###\n  ####\n #####\n######");
        if (height == 7)
        printf("      #\n     ##\n    ###\n   ####\n  #####\n ######\n#######");
        if (height == 8)
        printf("       #\n      ##\n     ###\n    ####\n   #####\n  ######\n #######\n########");

}
```

Comment: Did you try using exactly the prompt shown in the assignment, “Height: ”, not “Height of the pyramid in steps: ”? Did you try without the “Height must be between 1 an 8 steps. Try again. \n“ message, just reprompting with the original prompt an no error message, as the problem statement shows?

Comment: Thank you Eric. Yes, i did. The output is still the same. the Pyramid is printing, but not passing the test.

Comment: Is it correct to have no `\n` after the last line?

Comment: Which last line are you refering Gerhardh? When I had \n the printed pyramyd had one row plus.

Comment: Use only exact the prompt shown in the problem assignment. Do not print the error message not shown in the problem assignment. With those changes: Test putting a `\n` at the start of each printed string. Test putting a `\n` at the end of each printed string. Test putting a `\n` both at the start and at the end of each printed string.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I tried the variations of adding \n. The result is still the same- no pass "did you add too much trailing whitesoace at the end.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is due to syntax mistakes:

Incorrect:

```
if (height == 2)
printf(" #\n##"); // something missing here
```

Correct:

```
if (height == 2)
{
    printf(" #\n##\n");
}
```

Besides your approach, it's better to use a for loop in this exercises for it helps you learn C using its potential.

Comment: Braces are only required if there are multiple statements to execute. They can be omitted if there's only one statement (though it is clearer to include them).

Comment: @OldenKnight I tried that, it gave me the same errors.

Comment: I gave you a sample (height == 2) of what you need to do on all heights (1-8). You miss the \n on all heights. I ran check50 with your code modified and got all green.

Answer (score 0):

after your do while is loop evaluates to true, write a loop to iterate through the height entered. Write another loop to print dots (height - 1) times. (in decreasing order), write another loop to print hashes (height) times (in increasing order, since height can not < 0).

Comment: Thanks. My question is, why I have No pass results from the test. The output is in corect order, but still.

Comment: is not according to their test. think of like 'what if you will print 100 bricks'?. the main aim is write a generic code that automate the printing of the bricks from your side irrespective of size of bricks.

Comment: I agree about the test purposes, but I cannot understand why am I getting error about "too much trailing whitespaces"?

Comment: why not, look at the spaces you put on when height > 1. remember their test is automated and generic, its not a human reading you code. they don't even read your code they pass test values to it, so that there is no going to only one solution to a problem.